# Scheduling staff with specific job titles and certificates

Tags: word-problem, operations-research

I have a scheduling of staff program that I think can be solved using linear programming. However, I am stumped on how to formulate the equations.

---

**Problem:** I have a list of candidates with specific job titles and certificates. For example - a candidate can either be an *Engineer*, *Dredge Master* or *Technician*. Each person can hold certificates in *Firefighting*, *First Aid*, *Lifesaving*.

I need to select, for example,

- $3$ Engineers
- $2$ Dredge Masters
- $7$ Technicians

but between them, there must be

- $4$ First Aid certificates
- $2$ Lifesaving certificates
- $5$ First Aid certificates.

---

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are you seeking to maximise/minimise? Your constraints seems to imply something like Firefighting $= x_{1} \ge 4$, Lifesaving $= x_{2} \ge 2$, First aid $= x_{3} \ge 5$

Comment: I am trying to generate the options which fills the criteria of  engineers = 3,  Dredge Masters =2, Technicians =7, which also fills the criteria of Firefighting Cert ≥ 4, Lifesaving Cert ≥ 2 and First Aid cert ≥5.

This should give me a list of all possible employee combinations of which i can then pick based on minimization of cost.

Comment: An Employee can only have 1 Job title, but they can have multiple certificates.

Comment: I am currently solving it with iterations. so i would give each combination a "Scarcity" element and then selecting the role/certificate combination with the most scarcity. then repeat the process with a for loop.

I dont know how to structure the solution through linear programming at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have $n \geq 12$ candidates and binary matrices $\mathrm A, \mathrm B \in \{0,1\}^{n \times 3}$, where $a_{ij} = 1$ means that candidate $i$ has job title $j$, and $b_{ij} = 1$ means that candidate $i$ has certificate $j$. Let $\mathrm c \in \mathbb R^n$ be the cost vector, whose $i$-th entry is the cost of hiring candidate $i$.

Let $\mathrm x \in \{0,1\}^n$ be the decision vector, where $x_i = 1$ means that we hire candidate $i$. If we want to minimize the cost, we have the following binary linear program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathrm c^{\top} \mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm x = \begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 2\\ 7 \end{bmatrix}\\ & \mathrm B^{\top} \mathrm x \geq \begin{bmatrix} 4\\ 2\\ 5 \end{bmatrix}\\ & \mathrm x \in \{0,1\}^n\end{array}$$

Comment: One can solve such binary programs using [PuLP](http://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/).

Comment: Thank you very much. i will work on this over the weekend and let you know on the results.